# Override `[]=` method in ruby array

Tags: ruby

I have a class `CustomArray`:

```
class CustomArray < Array
  def initialize(row, col)
    @row = row
    @col = col
    @array ||= Array.new(size=row * col)
  end
end
```

How can I override the `[]=` method of `CustomArray`? I did:

```
class CustomArray < Array
  def []=(length, row, col)
    puts @array[0], col, row
  end
end
```

Regardless of a change I make to `@array`, the new instantiated array length remains zero.

I tried replacing the value of `self`, but it looks like `self` is read only.

Comment: I don't understand your question. First you ask "How to override the `[]=` method?", but you already know the answer - you've done it in the code sample. Then to talk about instantiating a new class instance... What does this mean, exactly? Can you provide an example of where you are creating a new instance, and explain what behaviour you'd like/expect? And then you talk about "replacing the value of `self`"... For a start, that's not possible (an object cannot change which object it is!) - but again, I don't really know what you mean since there's no code sample or explanation.

Comment: Perhaps it would be more helpful if you were to explain what it is you're *trying to achieve*, not *how you're trying to do it*. This question seems like a probable [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/369864) to me - it seems you're stuck with an unusual implementation, which could possibly be solved in a much simpler way.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need an `@array` instance variable when subclassing `Array`  – each instance already *is* an array.

Assuming that you are trying to implement a two-dimensional array on top of the build-in (one-dimensional) `Array`, something like this should work:

```
class CustomArray < Array
  def initialize(rows, cols)
    @rows = rows
    @cols = cols
    super(rows * cols)
  end

  def []=(row, col, value)
    super(row * @rows + col, value)
  end

  def [](row, col)
    super(row * @rows + col)
  end
end
```

However, Ruby's core classes are heavily optimized and subclassing them can be quite tricky (see https://words.steveklabnik.com/beware-subclassing-ruby-core-classes).

Therefore, it's usually easier to use composition instead of inheritance, i.e. do use an `@array` instance variable, but don't inherit from `Array`, e.g.:

```
class CustomArray
  def initialize(rows, cols)
    @rows = rows
    @cols = cols
    @array = Array.new(rows * cols)
  end

  def []=(row, col, value)
    @array[row * @rows + col] = value
  end

  def [](row, col)
    @array[row * @rows + col]
  end
end
```

Comment: ...Or perhaps it would be more practical to use ruby's standard library [`Matrix`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/matrix/rdoc/Matrix.html) implementation? It all depends what was trying to be achieved in the first place.

Comment: @TomLord although `Matrix` is tailored towards mathematical matrices, not two-dimensional arrays (or arrays of arrays) in general.

Comment: Excellent answer! @Tom, the fact that matrix objects are immutable may be another limitation.